# python how to draw a variable again if it is the same as another variable

Tags: python, random, while-loop, draw

I have two lists, basically the same number :

```
import random

A = [ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40 ] 
B = [ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40 ]
drawA =(random.choice(A))
drawB =(random.choice(B)) # want to exclude the number drawn in drawA
```

How can I ask python to draw again if `drawB == drawA`.

Or else, how can I draw a number from list B excluding the number already drawn in list A ?

Comment: Will `A` and `B` always be the same?

Comment: Why not just use `random.shuffle` followed by `list.pop`? Or, `drawA, drawB = random.sample(A, 2)`.

Comment: [**`random.sample`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample).

Comment: @PeterWood: It only works if `A == B`.

Comment: @EricDuminil `A` and `B` *are* the same, and OP hasn't clarified otherwise.

Comment: List A and list B are always the same. It is a separate drawing.

Answer (score 1):

Just exclude the value of drawA from B while finding the random number.

```
drawB = random.choice(filter(lambda num: num != drawA, B))
```

OR

keep looping until you get the desired result.

```
import random

A = [ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40 ] 
B = [ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40 ]

drawA = random.choice(A)
number = random.choice(B)
while number == drawA:
    number = random.choice(B)

drawB = number
```

Comment: What other options does the [**`random`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module offer?

Comment: @PeterWood I get sampling might work, but what if two lists were different.

Answer (score 1):

Search in a modified array which does not have drawA element.

```
import random

A = [ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40 ] 
B = [ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40 ]
drawA =(random.choice(A))
drawB =(random.choice([x for x in B if x != drawA]))
```

Answer (score 1):

At first we can create a generator for random numbers for B:

```
def gen_B():
    while True:
         yield random.choice(B)
```

And then select the first one that isn't the value used for A:

```
drawB = next(x for x in gen_B() if x != drawA)
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
import itertools
next(x for x in (random.choice(B) for _ in itertools.count()) if x != drawA)
```